# Conditioning and linear MSE

Tags: estimation, mse, conditioning, inequality

Let $\sigma_{X|Y}^2$ denote the linear mean squared error in estimating $X$ from $Y$. Then is it always true that additional conditioning cannot increase the LLSE? In other words, is this true?
$$ \sigma_{X|Y,Z}^2 \leq \sigma_{X|Y}^2$$

Comment: What it LLSE?..

Comment: Sorry... I meant linear mean squared error...as in $$ \sigma_{X|Y,Z}^2 = \min_{a,b} \mathbb{E}[(X-aY-bZ)^2]$$...